# data source terraform_remote_state with workspaces

Tags: terraform

I'm running terraform v0.14.8 with a non-default terraform workspace.

I have an Atlantis server that handles my plans and applies.

When I clone my repo locally and run my plans I get errors about my datasource. I don't quite understand why as I don't get these errors on my Atlantis server which I believe performs the same operations. The Atlantis server also uses tf v0.14.8.

My terraform:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "route53" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    key      = "web/terraform.tfstate"
    region   = "us-west-2"
    bucket   = "prod-terraform"
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/atlantis"
}
```

Before I run my local plan, i switch the workspace

```
terraform workspace select web

# in addition I also tried
export TF_WORKSPACE=web
```

My plan

```
teraform plan
...

Error: Unable to find remote state

  on provider.tf line 46, in data "terraform_remote_state" "route53":
  46: data "terraform_remote_state" "route53" {

No stored state was found for the given workspace in the given backend.
```

I could easily edit my  "key" with env: and things will work, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this without making that adjustment, seeing that my Atlantis server just works.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "route53" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    key      = "env:/web/web/terraform.tfstate"
    region   = "us-west-2"
    bucket   = "prod-terraform"
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/atlantis"
}
```

Comment: The error message implies your user on that server does not have access/authentication/authorization etc. for your backend.

Comment: I believe it's because there is no state file in the location that it is looking. it's not looking in env:/web/web/terraform.tfstate.

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to imply some confusion over which of these backends the `web` workspace is selected for. Running `terraform workspace select web` selects the `web` workspace from the backend of the *current* configuration (the directory where you are running Terraform), but I suspect your intent is to select the `web` backend from the backend you've configured in `data "terraform_remote_state"` instead.

If so, you can do that by setting the `workspace` argument in the data source configuration:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "route53" {
  backend   = "s3"
  workspace = "web"

  config = {
    key      = "web/terraform.tfstate"
    region   = "us-west-2"
    bucket   = "prod-terraform"
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/atlantis"
  }
}
```